Find R Shiny Log on Ec2
I have an EC2 instance with a shiny server installed and am wondering how I can get the latest log for the app.
The following has the logs for the shiny server, but I want the logs for the app
var/log/shiny-server


Have you enabled log preservation with preserve_logs true; in the shiny-server.conf ?

Yes, I have it there
